# How to write my first function in R markdown?

Tags: r

I am writing my first function in R Markdown but cannot quite seem to get it work. Can anyone help?

I am working with a character variable that lists dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd which I want to convert to a date formatted as 'Jan', 'Feb' etc. To do this I have used 2 steps:

1. Convert the character variable to a date formatted in the same way as the character as follows:

`All.abs$MonthBeginning= as.Date(All.abs$MonthBeginning, format= "%Y-%m-%d")`

2. Then to change the date to 'Jan' etc using the following code:

`All.abs$MonthBeginning= as.Date(All.abs$MonthBeginning, format= "%b")`

I want to follow this same process for the same variable (MonthBeginning) in 2 other data.frames (called 'Carbs' and 'Pip.Taz') without have to write 6 lines of code.

I have written the function (named chart_months) as follows but cannot seem to get it to work:

```
chart_months= function(x) {
  x= as.Date(x, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
  x= as.Date(x, format= "%b")
}
chart_months(All.abs$MonthBeginning)
chart_months(Carbs$MonthBeginning)
chart_months(Pip.Taz$MonthBeginning)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do that:

> Then to change the date to 'Jan' etc using the following code:
>
> ```
> All.abs$MonthBeginning= as.Date(All.abs$MonthBeginning, format= "%b")
> ```

you want to use `format`:

```
> string_date = "2001-05-22"
> date_object = as.Date(string_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
> short_month = format(date_object, "%b")
> short_month
[1] "May"
```

So your function should be:

```
get_short_month = function(string_date){
  date_object = as.Date(string_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
  short_month = format(date_object, "%b")
  return(short_month)
}
```